# Submitting a form in django with database elements

Tags: python, django, forms, view

I'm trying to do an specific quiz in Django. I've the database properly connected and the fields filled, so the information outputs well.

I'm having trouble with the form submission. In the 'questions.html' template it shows the question and the four multiple answers (from models). I get the answers displayed in a list (each answer inside a `<li>` element). I'd like to do that **by clicking on the `<li>`** element it automatically **submits** the answer of the question and passes to the next one.

I've tried several ways of making it work but I'm not getting to an answer. This is the **form** inside the **template HTML**:

```
<form id="game" action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="{{ question.id }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="answer">
  <ul class="list-group">

    {% for answer in form.answers %}
      <li class="list-group-item" data-answer="{{answers}}">
        <p class="answ">{{ answer }}</p>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Here's the **forms.py**:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, question, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choice_list = [x for x in question.get_answers_list()]
        self.fields["answers"] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choice_list,
                                                   widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

One of the tries included this **jquery** file including this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#game li').click(function() {
         $('input[name="answer"]').val($(this).data('answer'));
         $('#game').submit();
    });
});
```

I guess the problem might be in how the view recieves the information done by the user, but I can find a way to fix whatever is not working well. Here is the whole view function related to the quiztake (views.py):

```
class QuizTake(FormView):
    form_class = QuestionForm
    template_name = 'question.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, url=self.kwargs['quiz_name'])
        if self.quiz.draft and not request.user.has_perm('quiz.change_quiz'):
            raise PermissionDenied

        self.logged_in_user = self.request.user.is_authenticated()

        if self.logged_in_user:
            self.sitting = Sitting.objects.user_sitting(request.user,
                                                        self.quiz)
        else:
            self.sitting = self.anon_load_sitting()

        if self.sitting is False:
            return render(request, 'single_complete.html')

        return super(QuizTake, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        if self.logged_in_user:
            self.question = self.sitting.get_first_question()
            self.progress = self.sitting.progress()
        else:
            self.question = self.anon_next_question()
            self.progress = self.anon_sitting_progress()

        if self.question.__class__ is Essay_Question:
            form_class = EssayForm

        return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(QuizTake, self).get_form_kwargs()

        return dict(kwargs, question=self.question)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.logged_in_user:
            self.form_valid_user(form)
            if self.sitting.get_first_question() is False:
                return self.final_result_user()
        else:
            self.form_valid_anon(form)
            if not self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]:
                return self.final_result_anon()

        self.request.POST = {}

        return super(QuizTake, self).get(self, self.request)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuizTake, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['question'] = self.question
        context['quiz'] = self.quiz
        if hasattr(self, 'previous'):
            context['previous'] = self.previous
        if hasattr(self, 'progress'):
            context['progress'] = self.progress
        return context

    def form_valid_user(self, form):
        progress, c = Progress.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)
        guess = form.cleaned_data['answers']
        is_correct = self.question.check_if_correct(guess)

        if is_correct is True:
            self.sitting.add_to_score(1)
            progress.update_score(self.question, 1, 1)
        else:
            self.sitting.add_incorrect_question(self.question)
            progress.update_score(self.question, 0, 1)

        if self.quiz.answers_at_end is not True:
            self.previous = {'previous_answer': guess,
                             'previous_outcome': is_correct,
                             'previous_question': self.question,
                             'answers': self.question.get_answers(),
                             'question_type': {self.question
                                               .__class__.__name__: True}}
        else:
            self.previous = {}

        self.sitting.add_user_answer(self.question, guess)
        self.sitting.remove_first_question()

    def final_result_user(self):
        results = {
            'quiz': self.quiz,
            'score': self.sitting.get_current_score,
            'max_score': self.sitting.get_max_score,
            'percent': self.sitting.get_percent_correct,
            'sitting': self.sitting,
            'previous': self.previous,
        }

        self.sitting.mark_quiz_complete()

        if self.quiz.answers_at_end:
            results['questions'] =\
                self.sitting.get_questions(with_answers=True)
            results['incorrect_questions'] =\
                self.sitting.get_incorrect_questions

        if self.quiz.exam_paper is False:
            self.sitting.delete()

        return render(self.request, 'result.html', results)

    def anon_load_sitting(self):
        if self.quiz.single_attempt is True:
            return False

        if self.quiz.anon_q_list() in self.request.session:
            return self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]
        else:
            return self.new_anon_quiz_session()

    def new_anon_quiz_session(self):
        """
        Sets the session variables when starting a quiz for the first time
        as a non signed-in user
        """
        self.request.session.set_expiry(259200)  # expires after 3 days
        questions = self.quiz.get_questions()
        question_list = [question.id for question in questions]

        if self.quiz.random_order is True:
            random.shuffle(question_list)

        if self.quiz.max_questions and (self.quiz.max_questions
                                        < len(question_list)):
            question_list = question_list[:self.quiz.max_questions]

        # session score for anon users
        self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_score_id()] = 0

        # session list of questions
        self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()] = question_list

        # session list of question order and incorrect questions
        self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()] = dict(
            incorrect_questions=[],
            order=question_list,
        )

        return self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]

    def anon_next_question(self):
        next_question_id = self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()][0]
        return Question.objects.get_subclass(id=next_question_id)

    def anon_sitting_progress(self):
        total = len(self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()]['order'])
        answered = total - len(self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()])
        return (answered, total)

    def form_valid_anon(self, form):
        guess = form.cleaned_data['answers']
        is_correct = self.question.check_if_correct(guess)

        if is_correct:
            self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_score_id()] += 1
            anon_session_score(self.request.session, 1, 1)
        else:
            anon_session_score(self.request.session, 0, 1)
            self.request\
                .session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()]['incorrect_questions']\
                .append(self.question.id)

        self.previous = {}
        if self.quiz.answers_at_end is not True:
            self.previous = {'previous_answer': guess,
                             'previous_outcome': is_correct,
                             'previous_question': self.question,
                             'answers': self.question.get_answers(),
                             'question_type': {self.question
                                               .__class__.__name__: True}}

        self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()] =\
            self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()][1:]

    def final_result_anon(self):
        score = self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_score_id()]
        q_order = self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()]['order']
        max_score = len(q_order)
        percent = int(round((float(score) / max_score) * 100))
        session, session_possible = anon_session_score(self.request.session)
        if score is 0:
            score = "0"

        results = {
            'score': score,
            'max_score': max_score,
            'percent': percent,
            'session': session,
            'possible': session_possible
        }

        del self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]

        if self.quiz.answers_at_end:
            results['questions'] = sorted(
                self.quiz.question_set.filter(id__in=q_order)
                                      .select_subclasses(),
                key=lambda q: q_order.index(q.id))

            results['incorrect_questions'] = (
                self.request
                    .session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()]['incorrect_questions'])

        else:
            results['previous'] = self.previous

        del self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_data()]

        return render(self.request, 'result.html', results)
```

Where does the problem resides? What it needs to be fixed in order to accomplish what I'm wanting to do?

I'll answer any related question and hope we can find an answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you tried using jquery, what was the behavior?  Did the form get submitted at all?  Was the answer incorrect/blank?

Comment: The answers displayed well, but when I clicked (selected) any of them it doesn't get submitted.

Comment: When you mouseover the `<li>`, does it indicate that it has a javascript action attached to it?  After clicking, are you able to inspect the javascript console to see if any errors popped up?

Comment: I've added a CSS style 'cursor:pointer' in the <li> element so this is what I get. When I load the page the console shows no log, and when clicking on the elements it still doesn't show anything... Thank you for your replies.

Comment: This might not be the problem, but shouldn't it be `data-answer="{{answer}}"` instead of `data-answer="{{answers}}"`?  Did you inspect the rendered HTML to verify that the correct value is in `data-answer`?

Comment: I don't know why, but if I change it to '{{answer}}' in every <li> element I get an extra answer. If an answer is 'AXIS', above it, it appears an extra answer with this text 'AXIS"> and the border radius also. I'm thinking on it but idk why could this be happening, it may be something important in order to solve the problem.
As your other question, I definetly didn't do it. How may I do that? I guess this 'data-answer' element is just to say the server which answer's been picked. Thank you again.

Comment: Is `{{answer}}` plain alphabetic text, or does it contain HTML markup?  If it does, you can't use it directly as an element value.

Comment: I think it's just plain text, however I'm using the data-answer attribute to link it with javascript to try to submit the answer just by clicking on the id. I can't figure out another way of doing it, or how to make it work this way... thanks again for the reply.

Comment: Did the view recieves the **question_id**? Rather then assigning an input with _.val($(this).data('answer'))_, you could try using `name='answer' value={{answer}}` inside <li> tag and change the jquery acc. to that. Also try to console.log the data you are sending if its working or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I find it displaying the answers correctly as well with the code you provided (just with one line of <li> with the name and value=answer). However now it displays the answers with a "> at the end. How could it be? I've tried changing the jQuery according to the new format but I'm not sure how to do it, I've been trying some modifications but still can't get it work.
I'm not sure also if the view recieves the question id. I've copied the view in the first post, it may be need to be in 'form_valid' or 'get_context_data'? thank you very much

Comment: Please use @username so that the concerned person can view your comment. I will check your next post. Thanks