# Submit a form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms

I'm working in Django with a quiz web app that needs to keep a form submitted on every question. The questions are displayed just properly. The problem happens when trying to submit the form with the questions.

The answers of the question (multichoice, 4 answers) are displayed within `<li>` elements. I want that by clicking in the answer (so, clicking in the `<li>` element) the answer gets submitted so the next question can be displayed. I can't make it work, so I can't get any answer submitted. The form HTML looks like this:

```
<form id="game" action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="{{ question.id }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="answer">
  <ul class="list-group">

    {% for answer in form.answers %}
        <li class="list-group-item" name="answer" value="{{answer}}">
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And the jQuery is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#game li').click(function() {
         $('input[name="answer"]').val($(this).value('answer'));
         $('#game').submit();
    });
});
```

It happens nothing when clicking on the answers' `<li>`, and the console shows no log.
How may I make it work? Thankyou.

**EDIT 1:**

Yes I have the **views.py** that manage the quiz, here's a snippet:

```
class QuizTake(FormView):
    form_class = QuestionForm
    template_name = 'question.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, url=self.kwargs['quiz_name'])
        if self.quiz.draft and not request.user.has_perm('quiz.change_quiz'):
            raise PermissionDenied

        self.logged_in_user = self.request.user.is_authenticated()

        if self.logged_in_user:
            self.sitting = Sitting.objects.user_sitting(request.user,
                                                        self.quiz)
        else:
            self.sitting = self.anon_load_sitting()

        if self.sitting is False:
            return render(request, 'single_complete.html')

        return super(QuizTake, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        if self.logged_in_user:
            self.question = self.sitting.get_first_question()
            self.progress = self.sitting.progress()
        else:
            self.question = self.anon_next_question()
            self.progress = self.anon_sitting_progress()

        if self.question.__class__ is Essay_Question:
            form_class = EssayForm

        return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(QuizTake, self).get_form_kwargs()

        return dict(kwargs, question=self.question)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.logged_in_user:
            self.form_valid_user(form)
            if self.sitting.get_first_question() is False:
                return self.final_result_user()
        else:
            self.form_valid_anon(form)
            if not self.request.session[self.quiz.anon_q_list()]:
                return self.final_result_anon()

        self.request.POST = {}

        return super(QuizTake, self).get(self, self.request)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuizTake, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['question'] = self.question
        context['quiz'] = self.quiz
        if hasattr(self, 'previous'):
            context['previous'] = self.previous
        if hasattr(self, 'progress'):
            context['progress'] = self.progress
        return context

    def form_valid_user(self, form):
        progress, c = Progress.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)
        guess = form.cleaned_data['answers']
        is_correct = self.question.check_if_correct(guess)

        if is_correct is True:
            self.sitting.add_to_score(1)
            progress.update_score(self.question, 1, 1)
        else:
            self.sitting.add_incorrect_question(self.question)
            progress.update_score(self.question, 0, 1)

        if self.quiz.answers_at_end is not True:
            self.previous = {'previous_answer': guess,
                             'previous_outcome': is_correct,
                             'previous_question': self.question,
                             'answers': self.question.get_answers(),
                             'question_type': {self.question
                                               .__class__.__name__: True}}
        else:
........
```

Also this is getting its information from the this **forms.py**:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, question, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choice_list = [x for x in question.get_answers_list()]
        self.fields["answers"] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choice_list,
                                                   widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

I've changed the code you provided me and tried different combinations but still don't work. I can't get the form submitted and the console shows no errors. Is this impossible?

**Edit 2:**

when I change the HTML code and try to put the '`<li>`' tag like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item" name="answer" data-answer="{{answer}}">{{answer}}</li>
```

I get this as an output (in this case 2 possible answers, 2 `<li>` elements displayed):

[image]

And when I quit the 'data-answer' of the li element, it gets:

[image]

Now when I put the mouse on the text, it doesn't get `'cursor:pointer'` while before in the `'False">'` it did. However, when I click on it nothing happens. May it be a problem in the `'views.py'`? Before I used to use a 'submit' button and it worked well. @JacobWindsor

Did I give some light to the issue? I'm quite confused thank you for the answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submitting a form in django with database elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282956/submitting-a-form-in-django-with-database-elements)

Comment: The problem with the extra `">` is definitely because of incorrect HTML. The HTML you provided is fine but the one you have must have some inconsistencies. I would be the problem with `cursor:pointer` is also because of incorrect HTML.

Comment: May I ask, why do you want to have an AJAX submit on each answer? Why not just have a list of all questions and answers and then submit it with a button at the end?

Comment: I'm trying to make it easier and more interactive by just clicking the answer instead of picking the answer and then clicking submit, if it doesn't change the whole thing because this interactiveness needs a lot of code and new stuff. Answers are appreciated, thank you Jacob.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by your use case. It sounds like you want to send an AJAX request to your server whenever a multiple choice question is clicked. The server then responds with the next question that is rendered into the form. If this is the case then it is a little more complicated than what you have provided. You will need to:

1. Grab the selected answer (as you have)
2. Make an AJAX request to the server but not using the form submit function.
3. Store the answer on the server.
4. Render the next question

However, from the code and description you have provided I can see that the selector is incorrect.

Try this:

```
$('#game ul.list-group li').click(function(){...});
```

However, I would recommend using [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/) since the overhead is a lot lower if you have a lot of list items.

```
$('#game ul.list-group').on('click', 'li', function(){...});
```

This also helps if you want to dynamically add or remove questions since you will not need to bind any new event handlers. Since you say "the answer gets submitted so the next question can be displayed" I assume you are doing some kind of dynamic addition of questions.

Comment: I've edited the first post, maybe I'm doing something wrong. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you havn't closed you `li` tag

`<li class="list-group-item" name="answer" value="{{answer}}">{{answer}}</li>`

also li doesn't have value attribute so you can't catch it like that ....  try this

```
<li class="list-group-item" name="answer" data-answer="{{answer}}">{{answer}}</li>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#game li').click(function() {
         $('input[name="answer"]').val($(this).data('answer'));
         $('#game').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried it, and posted the results on the first post. Hope it can shed some light.

Comment: @Jim your `answer` variable contains html code , thats why you code is getting messed up when you use `data-answer="{{answer}}"` .... just put the value of radio button in  data-answer , also use firebug or chrome developer tools console to debug javascript